# Binding form from Frontend (angular) to model in backend ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, forms, asp.net-core, data-binding, deserialization

I'm having problems binding array of objects to a list in my backend. Everything binds correctly beside that one array.

Here are photos of my problem notice that list of PrepTimes is null:

- Controller with debug view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTrYb.png
- Fronted code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhdZY.png
- Payload: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ba6B.png

I tried all variations of:

```
    form.append(
      'prepTimes',
      JSON.stringify(this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime)
    );

    form.append(
      'prepTimes[]',
      JSON.stringify(this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime)
    );

    for (let prepTime of this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime) {
      form.append('prepTimes[]', JSON.stringify(prepTime));
    }

    this._recipeService.addRecipe(form);
  }
```

I tried removing and adding '[]', sending it without `JSON.stringify()` etc. I did all the variations I could do.

Console log for `this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime`:

```
this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime :>>  
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0: {title: 'Prep Time', time: 1, unit: 'mins'}
 1: {title: 'Cook Time', time: 1, unit: 'hours'}
 length: 2
 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: Try printing `this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime` and make sure it has a value first. Also try to add more of your code to the question, but please not as screenshots. Never share code as screenshots in a question.

Comment: @Zahema I provided console.log for `this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime` it is on the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post array of objects with `FormData` is different. You need to construct the `FormData` as:

```
prepTimes[0].title="Prep Time" 
prepTimes[0].time=1
prepTimes[0].unit="mins"

prepTimes[1].title="Cook Time" 
prepTimes[1].time=1 
prepTimes[1].unit="hours"
```

```
let recipePrepTime: any = this.recipeForm.value.recipePrepTime;

for (let i in recipePrepTime) {
    let prepTime = recipePrepTime[i];

    for (let k in prepTime) {
        form.append(`prepTimes[${i}].${k}`, prepTime[k]);
    }  
}
```

[Demo @ TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBATiDGCWAHEAFGiAq8C2IBcAhgHYCeEAvBANoBQE9EA3hGPGKHhAORoiIRZcXADQsc+CAEZRAVyJtOXbPCIBnLhAC+wug2at2ErgGEA9qYDWA8SLG5O0iHIXcAFqZlR1WmgF0A3DQ0oJAAZqZQ2JwAYhHYACIEYAQUEEQgAO4QsZGJyQAUAJSBNOFQEPkhEPDVRNBwSKjogiCFTLr0VYjN4qkwCMi8mOJU8AFBDBBlFVVWKhDdfC1tjB2TU3EAdASIyEQAJvkABovDuKpUACSM8Jq+m9cWmkeipy1UFr7Fa5r0NJpBab5ABuBHKiAI8HKplCG0imxARDAUHgIFURRWa1gpjUplAm2ApgA5vkIVCqAAGXwAam4lA0tLJUCoki+-gg-yAA)